# Функции обработки символьных строк

Tags: c++, функции, символы

В заданой строке символов найти обращение к тригонометрической функции  tg (х), где х, у - числа. Определить числовые значение аргументов  и вычислить эти функции.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобаться.  Не могу даже задание адекватно понять(

Comment: "...тригонометрической функции tg (х), где х, у - числа. " - А где здесь y?

Comment: Приведите точный текст задания

Comment: это полный текст задания

Comment: Очевидно же что задание сформулировано некорректно. Возможно банальная невнимательность, а возможно расчет на то что задание никто не будет делать. Ну Вы понимаете. Лучшим решением будет обсудить формулировку задания с преподавателем.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно могу посоветовать регулярные выражения, но у регулярных выражений в С++ такой ужасный API %)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::regex regex(
        "tg" "\\s*" "\\(" "\\s*" // match "tg" "("
        "([-+0-9.eE]+)" // match a number
        );

    std::string text = "bla-bla tg ( 10 ) bla-bla tg(1.2e+1)";

    for (std::sregex_iterator it(text.begin(), text.end(), regex), end; it != end; ++it) {
        auto x = std::stod((*it)[1].str());
        std::cout << "tg(" << x << ") = " << std::tan(x) << '\n';
    }   
}
```